# Datepicker not working after upgrade to jquery 3.3.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker

Im working a C# MVC project.  Datepicker stopped working and I narrowed it down to what is causing it but don't have a solution...

I change one line of code in the Layout page and it breaks the date picker.  Specifically going from jquery-1.11.1.min.js to jquery-3.3.1.min.js

This layout works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

This layout breaks datepicker:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Content/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

So the Datepicker doesn't pop a calendar below the input, just a thick white line above the input.

I haven't been able to resolve this.  Help?

Comment: Are you using the most up-to-date version of the datepicker library?

Comment: And the errors you're getting in the console are...?

Comment: No errors in console.  I'm working to figure out if I have the most up to date datepicker library.  I inherited this project, am going into Nuget Package Manager now.  Any idea what the most up-to-date version looks like/is?

Comment: I'm guessing this one? http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#nuget

Comment: Could you also please specify what datepicker and version you are using - Bootstrap datepicker or jQuery UI datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed Bootstrap.Datepicker v1.7.1....

It brought in some new .css files and overwrote some of what was in the project and now the datepicker calendar is working.

I neededthe new code in bootstrap-datepicker.css .  The code I had was not up to date. Also needed the new code in bootstrap-datepicker.js and bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

I deleted everything else the Package Manager brought in and everything works as intended.